# Flash: Link Flash .swf with another file on same cd

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have folder named JPAZZ and in this folder I have the following items:

**JP.swf** and **TEST.pdf**. Now the problem is the following. In **JP.swf** file, I would like to link some text with the **TEST.pdf** file WITHOUT using a hard link (in HTML I normally use a slash to make it work dynamically..Example: /TEST.pdf)

Currently I am using Action Script 3 in Flash and I am trying to link the text with TEST.pdf by using the Advanced Character Link as shown below:

Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put `TEST.pdf` in the link field (if it's in the same folder).

Note that this will only work if you run it from within a browser.